# Unable to add new libraries to Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, when i try to add a new library in the Settings, it gives me the error as "Error loading package list: pypi.python.org". See screenshot as well
I am using Pycharm community edition 2017.2 version. 
I need to add library for Tweepy and other libraries.
Please help...

[image]

Comment: have you tried pinging pypi.phython.org to ensure that everything is alright from the networking point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your repository to `https://pypi.python.org/simple`

Settings | Project | Project Interpreter | Plus sign | Manage Repositories | Edit | `https://pypi.python.org/simple` | Ok

If that doesn't work, and you aren't in a virtual environment, you could also install packages directly through the terminal using `pip`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I changed the proxy settings and added proxy details. Was able to add after that.
Went in System Settings>>HTTP Proxy>>Manual Proxy configuration
Updated Host name, port number. Got those details by going in my IE and checking proxy settings.